# How to instantiate class with nested abstract field with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, abstract

I've got following classes :

```
public class City
{
    Zoo zoo;
}

public class Zoo
{
    Animal[] animals;
}

public abstract class Animal 
{
    String name;

    abstract void eat();
}
```

I want to deserialize an instance of `City` class with Jackson. Howerer, since `Animal` is an abstract type, I've got following exception:

> Could not read JSON: Can not construct instance of Animal, problem:
>   abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom
>   deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information

How to map `Animal` to concrete type?

The problem is that I am able to modify **only** `City` class.

Comment: Use `@JsonDeserialize(as=ConcreteClass.class)` on the field using an abstract type

Comment: Read up on [polymorphic type handling](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization).

Comment: @VinceEmigh That's fine if there's only one type of `Animal`, but that would be a pretty sad zoo ;-)

Comment: @VinceEmigh As I wrote, the trick is that I cannot add anything to `Zoo` and `Animal` class.

Comment: @dnault Let's assume for simplicity that there is only one concrete Animal type :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one-to-one (abstract/impl) use case, registering sub-classes (which you can do via `ObjectMapper.registerSubtypes(...)`, or using `SimpleModule`) is an alternative to annotations.

But if you have truly polymorphic type, `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation is the key. It needs to be added in the base class that is used static type (like `Animal`), and will result in addition of a Type Identifier on serialization, and use of that id on deserialization.
There are multiple choices both for kind of type id (class name vs logical name) as well as inclusion style (as property, as wrapper array, as wrapper object, as external property).

Answer (score 2):

Since you can modify only the `City` class, you may find [mix-in annotations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations) useful. The idea is you create and annotate a a new class that acts as a surrogate for the class you wish you could annotate (but can't for whatever reason). Then you register your surrogate with Jackson, telling it to look for annotations on your surrogate instead of the actual class.

To start with, you could try creating a mix-in for `Animal` and annotating the mix-in class with `@JsonDeserialize(as=ConcreteClass.class)` as Vince Emigh suggested. Once you've got that working, you can try annotating it with [polymorphic type handling](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) annotations.